# Fit page full screen, and force div to stop at the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a full page/full screen design, and fit a map on this page.

I've been trying different solutions, but can't seem to fit/strecth the map.

This is my skeleton :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>
   <header>
   </header>
   <div id="container">
       <aside class="left-sidebar">
       </aside>
       <aside class="right-sidebar" style="overflow: scroll;">
       </aside>
       <div id="map"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
   html, body {
       min-height: 100vh; /* this fixed my problem with the page
       width: 100%;
       height: max-content; 
   }

   #container{
       padding-top: 20px;
       top: 100px;
   }

   header {
       height: 80px;
       padding: 20px;
       width: 100%;
       border-style: solid;
   }

   #map {
       flex: 1;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-left: 200px; /* Adjust the margin to match the width of the left sidebar */
       margin-right: 400px; /* Adjust the margin to match the width of the right sidebar */
       height: 100%;
       box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
       padding-bottom: 5px;
       border-style: solid;
   }

   .right-sidebar {
       position: fixed;
       right: 0;
       padding: 20px;
       width: 400px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
       height:100%;
       border-style: solid;
   }

   .left-sidebar {
       position: fixed;
       padding: 20px;
       width: 200px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
       height:100%;
       border-style: solid;
   }
```

So this  `min-height: 100vh;` fixed my problem with the full page. However, after implementing this, my map shrank. I've tried different solution for the map height but no success.

[image]

Do you have any idea how I could fix this ?

Comment: Note as posted it is somewhat unusual to see no closing `</head>` tag and also with your comment IN the CSS your CSS is malformed here `min-height: 100vh; /* this fixed my problem with the page`  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head#technical_summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your #map div where you are trying to set height 100%. It should be equal to (height of viewport - the height of header) for that you can use CSS dynamic function
height: calc(100vh - 20px):. use this
and also add flex properties to your body

Answer (score 1):

I know you have a great answer but might I suggest a slight change to the layout to wrap it all in a container then make that a grid.

You can work out the `minmax(8em, 25%)` for your left/right side bars and given you are going to have a map that map size would then drive the height as I did with the fake green block just for illustration.

I added a footer and a full width header with size both of which could have a calculated size OR just let them flow with the content they have also since that is often seen.  I used dashed borders just to show what is where but you could swap that for the solid I commented out.

Put this in full screen and then resize it a bit to see how it all reacts to that then just make the visual adjustments to sizes that please you the most.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto 1fr auto / minmax(8em, 25%) auto minmax(8em, 25%);
}

.section {
  border: dashed 1px #0000FF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  /*border-style: solid;*/
}

header {
  padding: 1em;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.left-sidebar {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.fake-map {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: #00ff0040;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}

.right-sidebar {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  overflow: scroll;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <header class="section">Header</header>
  <aside class="left-sidebar section">Left side</aside>
  <main class="section" id="map">
    <div class="fake-map">I am sized fake map</div>
  </main>
  <aside class="right-sidebar section">Right side</aside>
  <footer class="section">Footer</footer>
</div>
```